# Mysql: Sort result by two columns diffrence

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables here is my tables

table_trip

```
id  |  trip  |   limit

1       A        1000

2       B        2000
```

table_entry

```
id  |   tripid    |  quantity

1        1            100
2        1            100
3        2            500  
4        2            400 
5        1            200
```

i want to show the result like this

```
id   |  tripid  |  total_quantity   | balance(limit-total_quantity)
1         1              400                600
2         2              900                1100
```

And also want to show the result `order by balance`
How can i do this with single query

i have tried this query but its not working

`select a.limit,(SELECT SUM(b.quantity) FROM table_entry b
where b.tripid=1) as total_quantity from table_trip a where a.id=1 order by a.limit-balance`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `select a.limit,(SELECT SUM(b.quantity) FROM table_entry b
where b.tripid=1) as total_quantity from table_trip a where a.id=1 order by a.limit-balance`
but it shows only one row i want to get all results from the table

Comment: Where does the first column in the result set come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, e.tripid, sum(e.quantity) AS total_quantity,
(t.limit - sum(e.quantity)) AS balance
FROM table_trip t LEFT JOIN table_entry e
ON t.id = e.tripid
GROUP BY t.trip
ORDER BY 3;
```

**[Example..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a96fe/9/0)**

Comment: Where is the order by?

Comment: `ORDER BY 3` ?? Why `3`, why not `balance`?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Do you even know what does 3 means?

Comment: No, probably I'm missing something, never seen something like this!

Comment: @7alhashmi well, I have to say I've never seen that syntax before either, so would you care to explain instead of passing snyde remarks ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie & @mrlucmorin this is the number of the occurance in my select statement. `total_quantity` is the 3rd columns, so its easier just to write `order by 3`. You can try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a96fe/9/0

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want, maybe something like this :

```
SELECT table_trip.id AS tripid,
entries.total_quantity,
( table_trip.limit - entries.total_quantity ) AS balance
FROM table_trip
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT tripid, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity 
FROM table_entry GROUP BY   tripid ) AS entries ON table_trip.id=entries.tripid
ORDER BY balance ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select a.id,b.tripid,sum(b.quantity) as total_quantity,
    a.limit-sum(b.quantity) as balance from table1 a 
    inner join table2 b on a.id=b.tripid group by a.id,b.tripid,a.limit
```

### <kbd>[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3edcf/2)</kbd>